# Scrapy crawler gives out KeyError

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape drugs information from a UK site using Scrapy, but I am getting "KeyError: 'Item does not support field: title'". I can't figure out what's the problem here.

I have tried scraping using scrapy.Spider class using parse_item function. The x-paths seems to work fine. I must have some problem with Rule / LinkExtractor objects?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor 
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class EMCSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'emccrawler'
    allowed_domains = ['medicines.org.uk']
    start_urls = ['https://www.medicines.org.uk/emc/browse-medicines/']



     rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//ul[@class='browse']/li/a"), 
        callback= 'parse_item', follow=True),
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//a[@class='search-paging- 
        next']"), callback= 'parse_item', follow=True),
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='col-sm-9']/h2/a"), callback= 'parse_item', follow=True),
        )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.xpath("//div[@class='col-md-12 title']/h1/text()").get(),
            'company': response.xpath("//h2[@class='product']/a/text()").get(),
            'ingredient': response.xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6']/ul/li/text()").get(),
            'prescription': response.xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6']/p/text()").get(),
        }
```

--

Comment: Can you post the full error/traceback?

Comment: Your code seems to work for me so I suspect something strange is happening. How are you running the spider? If you run in a fresh directory (not in a project) with `scrapy runspider emc_crawler.py` does it work?

Comment: @tomjn: Here's the full error msg: https://pasteboard.co/ItX8oCa.png

Also, I get the same error message with scrapy runspider

Comment: sorry, last line got skipped in the image. here's the new one: https://pasteboard.co/ItYtnKh.png

Comment: (It would be better if you edited your post to include the traceback). But it looks like what you posted doesn't correspond to the code above? Towards the bottom you have `... emc_crawler.py", line 19 in parse_item"`. It doesn't look to me like line 19 is in `parse_item`. In addition, it says the line is `item["title"] = response.xpath...` which doesn't match what you have above. Are you sure the code above is what you are running?

Comment: @tomjn: thanks, i just created a new project and copied the crawler to the new project. It worked! Not sure what was going on, some issue with my project setup, or some misunderstanding with vscode terminal. I am a newbie.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry guys, but seems like there was some issue with my project setup. Just creating a new project and copying the crawler worked for me. 
Thanks to @tomjn and everybody for helping me resolve.